# javascript window.setInterval not working on latest Firefox and IE9

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i recently created a custom ping box(chat) for personal needs. When i coded it and tested in Firefox 3.6.13, it worked fine. However the functionality related to window.setInterval doesnt seem to work fine in IE9 or Firefox 6.

Below is the code for javascript.

```
    <script>

     function loadNewPosts(){
        var id = $(".altbgcolor:first").attr("id");

        $.get('/updateping.php', { updateid: id ,  }, function(data){
                                $(".newslist").prepend(data);
                            }, 'html');
     }

     window.setInterval(loadNewPosts, 1000*3)   


     $(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind form using ajaxForm 

             $("#pingForm").validate({


                submitHandler: function(form) {  
                $('#pingForm').ajaxSubmit({ 
                        // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
                        target: '#pingResult', 

                        // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
                        // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
                        success: function() { 

                            $('#msg').val('');
                            $('#pingResult').fadeIn('slow'); 
                            $('#pingResult').fadeOut(2000); 
                        } 
                    });
                }
            }); 

        })


 </script>
```

Below is the HTML

```
      <ul class="newslist" style="width:630px;">

        <li class="altbgcolor" id=64>
    <div>   
        <div class="newsthumb" style="width:50; height:50; "center center no-repeat;"><img src="images/personal/sunny.jpg" /></div>



        <div class="newstext" style="margin:0px;">


        <h1 style="color:#081C28;"><img width="11" height="9" src="/content/icon_topic_newest.gif">how r u?</h1>

        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div style="font-size: 0.6em; color:#666666;">  
            <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none; padding:5px;"><i> from: <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color:#105289 ;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = 'none'">Sunny</a></i></span>                          
            <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none; padding:5px; "><i> posted: <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color:#105289 ;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = 'none'">October 29, 2011, 9:58 am</a></i></span>                           
        </div>  

        <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>


    </li>
        </ul>
```

I tried to debug the problem using Firebug, but though it does seem that window.setInterval is able to call the .php file with required parameters every 3secs, however it doesnt show the o/p of the php file.

Code of php (updateping.php)

```
        <?

        require_once('includes/connection.php');
        require_once('includes/functions.php');

        if(isset($_GET['updateid']))
        {
            $updateid=$_GET['updateid'];
            $sql="SELECT * FROM ping WHERE id > $updateid ORDER BY id DESC";

            $res=mysql_query($sql,$connection);

            if(@mysql_num_rows($res))
            {
                while($data=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                        //while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                                echo '<li class="altbgcolor" id='.$data['id'].'>
                                    <div>   
                                        <div class="newsthumb" style="width:50; height:50; center center no-repeat;"><img src="'.$data['img'].'"  /></div>



                                        <div class="newstext" style="margin:0px;">


                                        <h1 style="color:#081C28;"><img width="11" height="9" src="/content/icon_topic_newest.gif">'.stripslashes($data['msg']).'</h1>

                                        </div>
                                        <br /><br />
                                        <div style="font-size: 0.6em; color:#666666;">  
                                            <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none; padding:5px;"><i> from: <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color:#105289 ;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = \'underline\'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = \'none\'">'.$data['name'].'</a></i></span>                          
                                            <span style="text-decoration:none; color:none; padding:5px; "><i> posted: <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color:#105289 ;" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = \'underline\'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = \'none\'">'.$data['entry_date'].'</a></i></span>                         
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                     </div>


                                    </li>'; 


                        }


            }

        }




        ?>
```

I am in a fix here and dont understand what could be the problem. That chatbox works fine on FF 3.6.13

Please help me someone!!!!!!!!!!!

**UPDATE:**
I tried the IE9 'F12' developer debugger and found that every 3 secs thought the php file is called the return result type 304-Not modified. :((

I went to 'Cache' options on the debugger menu and checked the option 'Always Refresh from server' and bammmm!!!! it worked now.

Any idea how to tweak this in actual IE and Firefox settings. The problem seems to be related to caching only.

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(data)` or `alert(data)` in the callback function of the `$.get()`? (Also, though presumably this isn't causing a problem if you've confirmed that your PHP is getting called every three seconds, you've got a trailing comma in the object `{ updateid: id ,  }` - some browsers tolerate trailing commas, some don't.)

Comment: I removed the trailing comma, yet no success :(( good find though ;). Yes the php file is being called every 3 secs, i checked tht in IE9 too, however its strange tht the o/p from the php is not shown on the main page. :((

Comment: But did you try the `console.log(data)` and/or `alert(data)`?

Comment: Not exactly, but read my update above, I think I got something...but not sure...BTW U want me to replace the $.get() with alert() in loadNewPosts() function?

Comment: No, don't replace `$.get()`. I meant temporarily put `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` instead of (or before) where you have `$(".newslist").prepend(data);` - just for debugging purposes to see what `data` is set to at the point you try to use it. And to confirm that that callback function is actually called. But it looks like you've already narrowed it down to the caching issue, so now there's no need for the alert/console.log

Comment: But whts the solution to this cache problem :(( Does it mean my script wud work only on certain browsers and not the rest. There must be something we cud do to solve this?

Comment: @nnnnnn I just tried the alert(data), it seems its returns blank popups only even though it shud contain the chat data :(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add a timestamp to your get request, or use post instead.

```
$.get('/updateping.php', { updateid: id , time: new Date().valueOf() }, function(data){
    ...
```

Or

```
$.post('/updateping.php', { updateid: id }, function(data){
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks gilly3, it worked. I tried the $.post() method. However I dont really understand the technical reason as to y this failed. COuld you explain it?

Comment: Browsers may cache `GET` requests, but they never cache `POST` requests.  Adding a timestamp to the end of a `GET` request causes the URL to be unique, thus bypassing the browser cache.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

As per the jQuery [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) doco jQuery will then append a timestamp to your request automatically so that the browser won't try to use the cache for subsequent requests.

Or you can try to fix the caching issue server-side with settings in the Cache Control section of the HTTP response header, but I don't know how to do that in PHP.